# How to find out the sender 's address in Android

Tags: android, networking

In C code there's this recvfrom function where you can find out the sender's IP address.

```
recvfrom(s, buffer, sizeof buffer, 0, (struct sockaddr *)&fromAddr, &fromAddrLen);
```

but in Android the data is

```
        byte[] buf = new byte[17];
        /* Prepare a UDP-Packet that can
         * contain the data we want to receive */
        DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(buf, buf.length);


        /* Receive the UDP-Packet */
        socket.receive(packet);
```

So, in Android how do you extract the sender's ip address?

Answer (score 0):

Per [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/net/DatagramPacket.html):

`packet.getAddress()`